# How to add a moving Flash in iPhone

Tags: iphone, flash

I want to add a flash that is a swf file in my application. Is there any simple way to do it programatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The iphone doesn't support flash at the current time, and no plans have been announced for future inclusion.

Answer (score 2):

At this time the iPhone doesn't support flash in any way (at least not in an approved app on an unlocked phone), so you won't be able to use a swf at all.  You might be able to accomplish something similar functionally using a pure javascript and html solution or using native graphics.  That will depend on what you are doing though.

Answer (score 0):

Given that Flash (and its precursors) have been around since 1995 and it still doesn't run well on my 8 core Mac Pro with 10 GB of RAM, I doubt it'll ever make it onto iPhones. Adobe simply hasn't shown the slightest bit of interest in optimizing Flash for Apple products.

Answer (score 0):

There is a parser soon to be available for dropping Flash SWF files into your app. It's still not available for download, but will play Flash animations directly from a SWF file inside a native app. http://www.flash-on-iphone.com/demo

Comment: Only about 2 years too late for you. Soz!