# Can we Integrate flash in iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, flash

I want to integrate flash in my iPhone application so is it possible to integrate?

Comment: Ngh... seriously? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone+flash

Comment: Agree with above, if you are in ANYWAY serious about iPhone development, how could you have missed all the press about flash not running on iPhone? Also a 2 second search would have answered your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a moving Flash in iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290047/how-to-add-a-moving-flash-in-iphone)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write apps in Flash that will run on the iPhone by using the [Packager for iPhone](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/packagerforiphone/). It only works with Flash and not Flash Builder. Adobe just released a revision after [Apple changed its SDK license again so that it can run](http://news.cnet.com/8301-30685_3-20015954-264.html). Note that to run on the iPhone your app has to be compiled by Flash to a native iPhone app. You can't run just any SWF.

Also yesterday [Adobe announced AIR 2.5](http://www.padgadget.com/2010/10/25/adobe-air-2-5-targets-the-ipadiphone-tvs-and-other-tablets/) which claims to let you program for one runtime (AIR) and target multiple platforms including iPhone and iPad. [The release notes](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/air25_whatsnew.html/) explain that they will be updating their Packager to work with AIR 2.5 for feature parity with AIR 2.5 for Android.

Answer (score 2):

There is an application called [Packager for iPhone](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/packagerforiphone/) from Adobe, which can be used to make iPhone app from Flash. I never used it though, but I think you should give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Adobe Packager appears to only be able to create entire apps, not library code that will integrate inside a larger app.  There also is no complete Flash interpreter in a form that you might be able to bundle with your app (although there appear to be a few open source projects that claim to run a limited subset of Flash).  Thus there is no way to integrate Flash into a larger iPhone application that will run offline.

Online, you might be able to run a Flash application remotely on a server, and serve the graphic results to an iPhone app using something like the VNC protocol.

Answer (score 0):

A new parser called hiramkei will soon be available for adding Flash animation SWF files into Xcode projects for iPhone. Here is the site http://www.flash-on-iphone.com/demo